How are royalties enforced in ERC721 contracts
I want to add royalties to my ERC721 contract. I found this _setTokenRoyalty method but I don't really understand what it does. Will it work on most marketplaces and will I receive a royalty fee whenever this NFT is sold? Is it possible to enforce royalties on the contract level or only on the marketplace level?
